# Analyzing songfile using fft when i set the song volume to 0 in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

In p5.js, I am using "new p5.FFT(x,y)" to analyze the amplifer mp3 file.

But this has a little problem that if you set the mp3's volume to 0(by using .setVolume(x)) the song file cannot be analyzed maybe because you set volume to 0 so there's no input.

So i want to know how to analyze songfile even when i set the volume to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is you need to connect your FFT at a point where the volume is still non-zero, and then have a node down stream where you control the volume. Here's an example where I've used the `p5.EQ` effect to control the volume of one part of the audio graph. The "Tada" sound is connected to an FFT and to the "mute" `p5.EQ` effect. This makes it so that the FFT visualizes the sound at full volume, but the slider controls how loud the sound actually is. The "Ding" sound on the other hand is connected directly to the output, no FFT, no volume control.

```js
let tada, ding;

let tadaBtn, dingBtn;
let volSlider;

let fft;
let mute;

function preload() {
  tada = loadSound('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/TADA.WAV');
  ding = loadSound('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/DING.WAV');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  let controls = createElement('div');
  controls.style('display', 'flex');
  controls.position(10, 10);

  tadaBtn = createButton('Tada');
  tadaBtn.mouseClicked(() => {
    if (!tada.isPlaying()) {
      tada.play();
      tadaBtn.html('Stop');
    } else {
      tada.stop();
    }
  });
  tadaBtn.parent(controls);

  tada.onended(() => {
    tadaBtn.html('Tada');
  });

  dingBtn = createButton('Ding');
  dingBtn.mouseClicked(() => {
    if (!ding.isPlaying()) {
      ding.play();
      dingBtn.html('Stop');
    } else {
      ding.stop();
    }
  });
  dingBtn.parent(controls);

  ding.onended(() => {
    dingBtn.html('Ding');
  });

  volSlider = createSlider(0, 1, 0, 0);
  volSlider.input(() => {
    mute.amp(volSlider.value());
  });
  volSlider.parent(controls);

  tada.disconnect();
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(tada);

  mute = new p5.EQ();
  mute.amp(volSlider.value());
  tada.connect(mute);
  mute.connect();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  drawSpectrumGraph(0, 0, width, height);
}

// Graphing code adapted from https://jankozeluh.g6.cz/index.html by Jan Koželuh
function drawSpectrumGraph(left, top, w, h) {
  let spectrum = fft.analyze();

  stroke('limegreen');
  fill('darkgreen');
  strokeWeight(1);

  beginShape();
  vertex(left, top + h);

  for (let i = 0; i < spectrum.length; i++) {
    vertex(
      left + map(log(i), 0, log(spectrum.length), 0, w),
      top + map(spectrum[i], 0, 255, h, 0)
    );
  }

  vertex(left + w, top + h);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```